# How can I use the force-click 'look up' function in Google Docs?

Tags: mac, google-docs, look-up

There is a Mac feature called 'look up' that when you hover over text that isn't editable (like any text, say on this website that isn't in a text field), and either force press on your trackpad or press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> it shows a definition and synonyms for a word.

I notice that you can do it to any words that aren't editable and even in some text editors like Microsoft Word and smaller ones. My problem is that it doesn't work in Google Docs. How could I bypass this on my Mac or in my browser?

Edit: I'm using the browsers Google Chrome and Firefox, on macOS
Sonoma 14.0. And even on some surrounding controls of Google Docs it doesn't work

Comment: OP please add which browser and macOS you have attempted this with as it may be different to what I've just tried. For other commenters note that as OP suggests, it doesn't work in Google Docs in Safari or Firefox on Sonoma (in the body of the document, it's OK on the surrounding controls etc). Web pages can be coded so the browser ignores right-click, or in this case force click, usually to prevent users using save images / web inspectors on page elements. What's needed is some sort of plugin? to unset the mouse click behaviour.